# How do you register your Nest Thermostat on the Developer Site

Tags: smart-device, nest-device-access

I am trying to use the Nest APIs to connect to my Nest Thermostat but I do not see the tie to my specific thermostat using a serial number or similar.  I have seen the various guides on how to get data once it is registered but not sure how to register it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 accounts you need to have an order to do API calls with nest platform.

1. You need a Nest account at home.nest.com. You should register your devices into this account (thermostats, smoke alarms, cameras etc)
2. You need a Nest Developer account https://developers.nest.com/ . Once you are logged into the nest developers, go the the console and create a product, add permissions etc.
3. Next, follow the steps in the official Nest Github account: https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk .

Technically, you can get a pin from calling the Authorization URL provided in nest developers, then use postman or Java to get the "access token". Once you have that you can do an API call to receive information from any device associated with your home.nest.com account.

If you use Java and android studio's, go through the explanation provided by Nest Labs, and when you run the code it will pop up a webview window and you will log your home.nest.com account that will connect it to your developer account and if you initialize the Listeners, you will receive all of the information you are looking for.